# showing dropdownlist on modal window MVC4

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

So, I'm fairly new to this stuff of MVC, but I have a back track of 10 years on ASP.Net, and I'm tearing my head up on how something so simple on either asp.net web forms or clean, simple javascript is taking me so much time to solve.

The thing is, I'm creating something of a base template for several types of project, and therefore, there's CRUD operations on my controllers and view. Everything work alright so far.

Now, The CRUD operations of my controllers, I'm loading them on a modal window, and for UI purpose, I'm using BootStrap. Create, Edit, Delete or View Details views are loaded on a modal window called on the Index View without a problem, for this I'm using the `$("#modalContent").load(url)` then `$("#modal").modal("show")`, piece of cake, and have worked correctly so far. I just got to a scenario that I'm having issues.

In one View, I had this drop down list, which one of its values, must show another dropdown list, from where the final value of the model property will be assigned. Here's the afformentioned view code

```
@model Sysbat.Models.Property

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DetailsLayout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Create</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" onload="setDDLEvents">
        <div class="editor-field form-group input-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "input-group-addon" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        <div class="editor-field form-group input-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "input-group-addon" })
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlSimpleType", (SelectList) ViewBag.ListTypes, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlSimpleTypes" })
        </div>
        <div id="complexType" class="editor-field form-group input-group" style="display:none">
            @Html.Label("Complex Type", new { @class = "input-group-addon" })
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlComplexType", (SelectList) ViewBag.ListComplexTypes, new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddlComplexTypes" })
        </div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Type, new { id = "hdnTypeValue" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success" />
    </div>
}
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#ddlSimpleTypes").on("change", function () {
                var val = $(this).val();
                if (val === "Complex") {
                    $("#hdnTypeVal").val('');
                    $("#ddlTiposObjetos").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#hdnTypeVal").val(val);
                    $("#ddlTiposObjetos").hide();
                }
            });
            $("#ddlComplexTypes").on("change", function){
                    $("#hdnTypeVal").val($("#ddlComplexTypes").val());
            });
        };
    </script>
}
```

So, if the code its not clear, whatever value `ddlSimpleType` has will be stored in the `model.Type` property via the hidden field is binded to, but, if the `ddlSimpleType` dropdown is set as 'Complex'. then a dropdown with the complex types will be shown and its value set, which also will be storing the selected value to the afformentioned hidden field.

The problem i'm facing is, that the function to set the fields events is not being fired.

I had read that partial view is not possible to do this kind of things, but this are complete view, also, I don't want to have to create a single js for each view that uses special javascript logic, I rahter have it inline.

Any suggestion?

Here's the layout code if its of any help

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        @RenderBody();    
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the drop down lists are part of your load, they are replacing the items that have the events attached to them by your document.ready. You may need to rebind the event listeners after the load() completes.

On another note, I don't see a #modalContent in your code sample.

Comment: #modalContent is located on the layout that the index view uses to load. The Create/Edit/Delete/Details view are using a details layout which is loaded into the index view in a bootstrap modal window

Comment: What if you code your onchange events into the htmlattributes and name the functions instead of binding them on document load?

Comment: Look to be working alright.... in Chrome. As far as I'm aware, IE, even on Edge, has issues with onchange, hence why I was using jquery, to not be messing with this

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end I got one of those momment where the answer appeared right in front of me.

I tested using `$(document).load()`, its my favorite method to execute code once the page is loaded, but then, I remembered that there was also the ready statement so I tested with `$(document).ready()` and it worked flawless.